# How to create a new column in R based on what another column starts with

Tags: r, startswith, mutate

My df contains demographic information on 50 people. I have a column in my df called "Ethnicity" which contains a lot of ethnicity categories including "White British", "White Other", and "White Irish". I want to create a new column where all observations with one of these 3 values is classified as "White", and all observations which don't start with "White" are classified as "POC".

```
df %>% mutate(Status = case_when(startsWith(Ethnicity, "White") ~ "White"))
```

I get the following error

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `Status = case_when(startsWith(Ethnicity,
  "White") ~ "White")`.
Caused by error in `startsWith()`:
! non-character object(s)
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: That's not the error you should get for a character column, is `df$Ethnicity` a factor? You can check with `str(df$Ethnicity)` . Or better yet, if you are OK with sharing bits from your dataset, add output from `dput(head(df))`  to your question.

Comment: `startsWith` cannot take non-character values(e.g. factor) as input. Try `df %>% mutate(Status = case_when(startsWith(as.character(Ethnicity), "White") ~ "White"))`

Answer (score -1):

Please check the below code with `adsl` dataframe. 
 Here i am using the `ETHNIC` with `HISPANIC OR LATINO` or `NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO` and i am creating a new column with all that starts with `HISP` as `HIS` and all others as 'NON', just for example

```r
library(tidyCDISC)
library(tidyverse)

data(adsl,package='tidyCDISC')

adsl %>% select(USUBJID, ETHNIC) %>% 
mutate(new_column=case_when(str_detect(ETHNIC,'^HISPA')==T ~ 'HIP',
                                                            TRUE ~ 'NON'))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 254 × 3
   USUBJID     ETHNIC                 new_column
   <chr>       <chr>                  <chr>     
 1 01-701-1015 HISPANIC OR LATINO     HIP       
 2 01-701-1023 HISPANIC OR LATINO     HIP       
 3 01-701-1028 NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO NON       
 4 01-701-1033 NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO NON       
 5 01-701-1034 NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO NON       
 6 01-701-1047 NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO NON       
 7 01-701-1097 NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO NON       
 8 01-701-1111 NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO NON       
 9 01-701-1115 NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO NON       
10 01-701-1118 NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO NON       
# … with 244 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: I think even if I replace `str_detect(ETHNIC, '^HISPA')` with `startsWith(ETHNIC, "HISPA")`, the output is still correct. So why you recommend using `str_detect` to replace `startsWith`?

Comment: i was not aware of `startsWith`, i regularly use 'str_detect' so i suggested the same. But now i am aware of `startsWith` as well which is a good thing.

Comment: The problem is that the OP has used `startsWith` but the code still broke out. Your post provide a workaround (i.e. `str_detect`), but you don't answer why `startsWith` failed for OP's case.